# Issues with encoding - working on one webserver but not another

Tags: php, apache, encoding, httpd.conf

I'm completely lost at the moment. I've been using a PHP scripts which read in Hebrew characters from two different sources; a CSV file (UTF-8) and a website (UTF-16). But since I've moved webhost the the characters from the CSV file are not showing up on the page.

The completely identical file runs perfectly on my previous webhost (hostgator) but since I've moved to a VPS its not printing the characters from the CSV file.

When I read from the website the page still shows the characters, but the CSV file doesn't.

I read in the CSV file using `array_map('str_getcsv', file('tAreas.csv'));`. On the previous webhost, the elements would be in UTF-8, on the VPS the elements are ASCII (Not sure whats causing the difference or how to rectify it).

I assume its something to do with the configuration of my webserver, though not entirely sure what needs to be done. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are all PHP setitngs the same? Especially mbstring ones? WHat are the default encodings of PHP and Apache on each system?

Comment: The settings aren't identical but I haven't deliberately changed anything. The only difference between the mbstring settings are the old webhost has the setting libmbfl version 1.3.2 - the VPS doesn't have this. Both of the encoding are set to UTF-8.